# How to add tag in dropdown menu to some selected categories

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, phtml

I'm using webandpeople extension to display my categories in dropdown list, i want to add some tags like new to some categories,
 plz provide me details how and where to add code to do it

this is display of my website
[image]

I want to display something like

[image]

Comment: it's dynamic or static

Comment: it is dynamic..

Comment: I dint get where to add code so that it displays to specific product

Comment: That extension uses default category tree for menu and wrap it within some fancy HTML. You'll need to re-write menu block to add these tags within your HTML. It might be based upon some custom attribute you set in category entity.